# Как работает функция memmove в C?

Tags: c, указатели, память

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь разобраться как работает функция memmove из стандартной библиотеки C.

Сама функция:

```
void    *ft_memmove(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    const char  *s;
    const char  *lasts;
    char        *d;
    char        *lastd;

    d = dst;
    s = src;
    if (d < s)
        while (len--)
            *d++ = *s++;
    else
    {
        lasts = s + (len - 1);
        lastd = d + (len - 1);
        while (len--)
            *lastd-- = *lasts--;
    }
    return (dst);
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что происходит в данной части функции:

```
else
        {
            lasts = s + (len - 1);
            lastd = d + (len - 1);
            while (len--)
                *lastd-- = *lasts--;
        }
```

Comment: Какое отношение функция с названием `ft_memmove` имеет к стандартной `memmove`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lasts = s + (len - 1);  // Указатель на последний байт блока s
lastd = d + (len - 1);  // Указатель на последний байт блока d
while (len--)           // len раз
    *lastd-- = *lasts--;// выполняем копирование из блока d в блок s
                        // После копирования байта указатели уменьшаются
```

т.е. простое копирование памяти не "слева направо", а "справа налево".

Смысл всего действа - чтоб не затереть копированием нужное при перекрывающихся областях памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Если эта `ft_memmove` действительно является реализацией (или частью реализации?) стандартной функции `memmove`, то надо заметить, что реализация функций стандартной библиотеки языка С не обязана быть написана на языке С и не подчиняется требованиям языка С.

Если рассматривать приведенный вами участок кода как код на языке С, то он внешне выполняет (пытается выполнять) копирование участка памяти "в обратном направлении" - от старших адресов к младшим. Однако с точки зрения языка С приведенный код делает это неправильно - на последней итерации цикла копирования происходит применение оператора `--` к значениям указателей `lastd` и `lasts`, потенциально указывающих в этот момент на *начала* неких массивов. Это формально приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Так что с точки зрения формального языка С код является некорректной реализацией `memmove`. Если этот код действительно позаимствован из реализации стандартной библиотеки, то это не С, а нечто внешне С-подобное. Чтобы говорить о том, что именно он делает, надо знать особенности поведения той платформы для которой этот код написан. Если же это пользовательский код, то вышеуказанная проблема делает его просто некорректным.

Comment: *"некорректных значений указателей `lastd` и `lasts` и возникает неопределенное поведение"* - а можно немного подробнее? Они же после этого не разыменовываются, никак не используются...? Тогда и первый цикл тоже содержит UB? (Молчу уж про итераторы .`end()` в C++)

Comment: @Harry: Я веду речь с чисто формальной точки зрения: адресная арифметика языка С не позволяет даже *формировать* указатель на воображаемое место "перед началом массива". За последним элементом - можно, перед первым - нельзя. С практической точки зрения все, конечно, "будет работать", но тем не менее.

Comment: А можно ссылку на стандарт? потому что не понимаю. чем отличается место *перед* от место *после*...

Comment: @Harry: Онлайновой версии стандарта С я не знаю. А так правила адресной арифметики для указателей описаны в "6.5.6 Additive operators", параграф 8. В частности: "...If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Место "перед" отличается тем, что потенциально вызывает "overflow". Например, на платформе с сегментной организацией памяти массив может начинаться прямо с начала сегмента. В такой ситуации вычитание чего-либо из адреса нулевого элемента приводит к "завороту".

Comment: Так ведь тут про UB в отношении значений указателей, а не всей программы! Да, по окончании цикла в этих `lastd` и `lasts` может быть любая фигня... которая никак не влияет на работу программы, так что на уровне выполняемой программы никакого UB нет.

Comment: @Harry: Мне не знакомо понятие "UB в отношении значений указателей, а не всей программы". Что это значит? UB есть UB. Как это "в отношении значений указателей, а не всей программы"? Если программа содержит UB, то программа содержит UB.

Comment: Ну что поделать... Тут уж я ничем помочь не могу :) Для себя я вопрос решил, за что спасибо, ну а в филозофские споры, что есть UB, а что нет, я вдаваться не буду :)

Comment: @Harry Тут нет никаких споров. Понятие UB в языке С определено достаточно четко и однозначно. Никаких споров не нужно - о том и речь. Я лишь попытался понять, что именно вы имеете в виду. Но раз вы в этом увидели "споры", то, видать, не судьба...

Comment: Кстати, а каково определение UB? Как оно дается формально? А то ведь использование неинициализированной локальной переменной - UB, а ее объявление... тоже, с вашей точки зрения - о том, что неопределенное значение переменной тождественно UB программы...

Comment: @Harry: Я никогда не говорил, что объявление неинициализированной переменной является UB. В данном примере причиной неопределенного поведения является попытка вычитания 1 из указателя, потенциально указывающего на начало массива. То есть к UB ведет именно применение оператора `--`. Именно это я хотел сказать под "потенциально происходит формирование некорректных значений указателей". Да, согласен, что это не очень хорошая формулировка. Исправлю